# Is there any possibilities to fetch the login details upto the given date in twitter using rest api's?

Tags: twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j, sttwitterapi

In my app, I want the login details of the user i.e when and where(IP address)the user is login into the account.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible at all in the Twitter API.

Comment: Can u please tell me sir, is there any way to fetch the login details of the user?

Comment: No, there is no access to any of this information via the API. Twitter uses OAuth so that a developer will only ever receive an access token from the API, no direct login information.